# jQuery lightbox-like message box

Tags: jquery

Is there - as far as you know - a lighbox-like jQuery plugin that can display text in a lighbox fashion?

I would need to display information and error messages in a message box which should behave just as a lightbox (i.e. shadowing background).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, here are some:

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

An article from two years ago with a list of ten: http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts

One which isn't maintained, but which lists others on its home page: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/